# Is there a way to place an in-app phone call, aside from custom URL schemes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way we can call phone numbers from iPhone App other than

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

I have used 'in app email and sms' using MFMailComposer and MFMesageComposer. 
Is there something similar to that for making a call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, custom url schemes like this (`tel://`) are the only official way Apple allows you to communicate with other apps (including the Phone app).

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the URL with `tel://`

```
[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL:[ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel://%@", phoneNumber ] ] ];
```

Comment: sorry, my question is there an way other than this. I have used this before.

Comment: I think URL identifier should be just `tel://`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the "OneTap" app, it is free on Apple app store
It does just that.